# How to style the slider?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I found [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/xaml-styles)... But Imma noobie yet too much to get how to apply it for my slider.
I have this now:

```xml
<Slider Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="6 0 0 0">
    <Slider.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
            <GradientStop Color="#ff0000" Offset="0.0" />
            <GradientStop Color="#ffff00" Offset="0.2" />
            <GradientStop Color="#00ff00" Offset="0.4" />
            <GradientStop Color="#00ffff" Offset="0.6" />
            <GradientStop Color="#0000ff" Offset="0.8" />
            <GradientStop Color="#ff00ff" Offset="1.0" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Slider.Background>
    <Slider.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                 // As I understood I can change styles here
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Slider.Resources>
</Slider>
```

But I can't get how to make to `Slider` has a gradient background for all states and themes, i.e. always, to it won't be black on the pointer hover and etc?

Can anyone post example, pls?

**ADDED**
Is this so hard question that noone knows? Or did I ask bad? Write me then, pls, I'll add details. Cuz I can't find a solution really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a document about the default style and template for the Slider control. You can modify these resources and the default ControlTemplate to give the control a unique appearance. Please refer [Slider styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299153.aspx).

From the default style, it define a `Rectangle` that named `VerticalTrackRect`. It is the "line" in the `Slider`, the Fill property bind to `Background` property of the `Slider`. So you should be able to set `LinearGradientBrush` to the `Background` property of `Slider`.

If you want to use `LinearGradientBrush` to the `Background` of `Slider` when the `Slider` is Pressed and PointerOver. From the default style, it use the `SliderTrackFillPointerOver` ThemeResource to set the `Fill` of `VerticalTrackRect` in the PointerOver. And it use `SliderTrackFillPressed` ThemeResource  in the Pressed.

So we should be able to set `LinearGradientBrush` to the `SliderTrackFillPressed` and `SliderTrackFillPointerOver`.

For example:

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <StaticResource x:Key="SliderTrackFillPressed" ResourceKey="MyLinearGradientBrush" />
    <StaticResource x:Key="SliderTrackFillPointerOver" ResourceKey="MyLinearGradientBrush" />
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MyLinearGradientBrush" StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
        <GradientStop Color="#ff0000" Offset="0.0" />
        <GradientStop Color="#ffff00" Offset="0.2" />
        <GradientStop Color="#00ff00" Offset="0.4" />
        <GradientStop Color="#00ffff" Offset="0.6" />
        <GradientStop Color="#0000ff" Offset="0.8" />
        <GradientStop Color="#ff00ff" Offset="1.0" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Slider Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="6 0 0 0" Background="{StaticResource MyLinearGradientBrush}">
    </Slider>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I found Blend (just I didn't use it never early), it allows to copy a template and override different states. But it generates a lot of code, this solution is much shorter.